# Replace command output with custom error message

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have been trying to change the output of `ls` without changing permissions. When the user writes `ls`, I want to print some kind of error like `command not found`.

I tried doing this with an alias but it's not working.

```
alias ls=error >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
alias ls="echo sorry ls command not found"
```

You can do that simply with `echo`:

```bsh
echo 'alias ls="echo sorry ls command not found"' >>~/.bashrc
```

Every newly opened terminal will now print your error message when you run `ls`:

```bsh
$ ls
sorry ls command not found
```

If you want to call the actual `ls`, use one of the following approaches to bypass the alias:

```bsh
/bin/ls
\ls
command ls
```